# Waitress doesn't show anything when starting WSGI application

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I want to run a flask app on waitress and it's not working.
My code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app)
```

When I try to run the app from cmd it gets stuck and doesn't do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it's stuck? By default waitress has log level set to WARNING, so you don't see any debug outputs.
Try changing logging configuration, like this:

```html
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's the full snippet

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

app = Flask(__name__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    serve(app)
```

running `python3 main.py` and stdout looks like this:

```
2022-10-03 14:53:14,410 Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

So, it was not stuck, just the logs were disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try running "waitress-serve".  I had the same issue.
For example, "waitress-serve --port=80 webproject.wsgi:application" worked for me.